# Laravel: \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm a newbie to this laravel.

i've followed a tutorial and i've checked that i wasn't do anything wrong, and then this error comes up. in this code i tried to Read data from table Inputs and create a page to Insert Data into the database in Inputs table.

TicketController:

```
public function index(){
    $inputs = Inputs::all();
    return view('index', [
        'inputs' => $inputs
    ]);
}
public function create(){
    return view('create');
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = new Inputs();

    $inputs->inputName = $request->inputName;
    $inputs->inputAddress = $request->inputAddress;
    $inputs->inputBDO = Carbon::parse($request->inputBDO);
    $inputs->inputEmail = $request->inputEmail;
    $inputs->inputPhone = $request->inputPhone;
    $inputs->inputJob = $request->inputJob;

    $inputs->save();

    return redirect('/input');
}
```

}

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'TicketController@index');
Route::get('/input/create', 'TicketController@create');
Route::post('/input', 'TicketController@store');
```

Comment: Post your blade view code as well

Answer (score 2):

In laravel `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` comes when you are referring a route which is not available or its type is mismatch. In your case the issue is same, and it is:

```
return redirect('/input');
```

&

```
Route::post('/input', 'TicketController@store');
```

for the first time when you are posting the from at that time the route method match, but at the time of redirection it is looking for:

```
Route::get('/input', 'TicketController@store');
```

which is not present, that's why the error.

Comment: In that case use `return redirect('/');`

Comment: Thanks. Helped me to understand the proper use of "routes"

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting back to `/input` at the end of your `store()` function. A redirect is done using a `GET` request, but you only have a `POST` route assigned to this url.

```
Route::post('/input', 'TicketController@store');
```